# Matisse vertical Flow Layout

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, matisse

Is there a way to create Netbeans Matisse Vertical Flow Layout like :

[image: Vertical Flow Layout]

But Netbeans Matisse Flow Layout create like this :
 [image: Horizontal Flow Layout]

Comment: Take a look at [SwingLabs, SwingX](https://java.net/downloads/swingx/releases/1.6.2/) `VerticalLayout`

Comment: Use a vertical BoxLayout or a GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 1):

`FlowLayout` will automatically "wrap" components whose width extends past the boundary of the container they're in. So, to accomplish *what I think* you're trying to accomplish, all you need to do is set the `FlowLayout` like you've done, and resize the `JTextField`s to the appropriate width.

Note: "what I think" was a pointed criticism of the fact that your question doesn't really help us know exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Five `JTextField`s:

[image]

Notice if you resize one, it will "wrap" the others:

[image]

You can select and resize multiple components simultaneously:

[image]

I changed the widths to 250:
[image]

Viola:

[image]

Code:

```
public class NewJFrame2 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJFrame2
     */
    public NewJFrame2() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(287,200);
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.FlowLayout());

        jTextField1.setText("jTextField1");
        jTextField1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 20));
        getContentPane().add(jTextField1);

        jTextField2.setText("jTextField2");
        jTextField2.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 20));
        getContentPane().add(jTextField2);

        jTextField3.setText("jTextField3");
        jTextField3.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 20));
        getContentPane().add(jTextField3);

        jTextField4.setText("jTextField4");
        jTextField4.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 20));
        getContentPane().add(jTextField4);

        jTextField5.setText("jTextField5");
        jTextField5.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(250, 20));
        getContentPane().add(jTextField5);

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame2.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new NewJFrame2().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```